# Send Invoice mail to customer

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

We are using Marketplace Extension, so seller can also process their order from their end it's working fine

```
public function saveTrackingNumberAction(){
            try{
                if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
                    $orderid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
                    $trackingid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('tracking_id');
                    $carrier=$this->getRequest()->getParam('carrier');
                    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                    $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
                    $items=array();
                    $shippingAmount=0;
                    $trackingsdata=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                                     ->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                                     ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($itemid);
                    foreach($trackingsdata as $tracking){
                        $tracking->setTrackingNumber($trackingid);
                        $tracking->setCarrierName($carrier);
                        $tracking->save();
                        $product_name="";
                        $shippingAmount=$tracking->getShippingCharges();
                        $items=explode(',',$tracking->getItemIds());
                        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
                            if(in_array($item->getId(),$items)){
                                $product_name =$product_name.$product->getName()." ,";
                            }
                        }

                        $product_name = $product->getName();
                        $to = $order->getCustomerEmail();

                        $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('trackingnopartner');
                        $emailTempVariables = array();              
                        $adminEmail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $product_name;
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $trackingid;
                        $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);
                        $emailTemp->setSenderName('Admin');
                        $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                        $emailTemp->send($to,'Admin',$emailTempVariables);
                    }

                        /**/
                    $itemsarray = $this->_getItemQtys($order,$items);

                    if(count($itemsarray)>0){
                        if($order->canInvoice()) { 
                            $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($itemsarray['data']);
                            $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
                            $invoice->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
                            $invoice->setSubtotal($itemsarray['subtotal']);
                            $invoice->setBaseSubtotal($itemsarray['baseSubtotal']);
                            $invoice->setGrandTotal($itemsarray['subtotal']+$shippingAmount);
                            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($itemsarray['subtotal']+$shippingAmount);
                            $invoice->register();

                            $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                        ->addObject($invoice)
                                        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
                            $transactionSave->save();
                            $order->sendNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment(
                                Mage::helper('mpshippingmanager')->__('Notified customer about invoice #%s.', $invoice->getId())
                            )
                            ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
                            ->save();
                            $seller_invoice_id = $invoice->getId();
                        }else{
                            if($order->hasInvoices()) {
                                foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) { 
                                    foreach ($inv->getAllItems() as $item) { 
                                        $product_id = $item->getProductId();
                                        $seller_pro_coll=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                                                                ->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$product_id))
                                                                ->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                                        foreach ($seller_pro_coll as $value) {
                                            if($value->getMageproductid()){
                                                $seller_invoice_id = $inv->getId();
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        $shipment = false;              
                        $shipmentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id');         
                        $orderId = $orderid;    
                        if($shipmentId){
                            $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentId);
                        }elseif($orderId){
                            $order  = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
                            if (!$order->getId()) {
                                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order no longer exists.'));
                                return false;
                            }
                            if($order->getForcedDoShipmentWithInvoice()){
                                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot do shipment for the order separately from invoice.'));
                                return false;
                            }
                            if(!$order->canShip()){
                                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot do shipment for the order.'));
                                return false;
                            }

                            $savedQtys = $this->_getItemQtys($order,$items);
                            $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($savedQtys['data']);
                        }
                        $shipment->register();
                        $comment = '';
                        $shipment->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(1);
                        $responseAjax = new Varien_Object();
                        $isNeedCreateLabel = isset($data['create_shipping_label']) && $data['create_shipping_label'];
                        if ($isNeedCreateLabel && true) {
                            $responseAjax->setOk(true);
                        }

                        /* Custom Code */
                        $shipment->getOrder()->setState('Invoice');


                        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                    ->addObject($shipment)->addObject($shipment->getOrder())->save();

                        /* Custom Code */


                        /*sale list status update*/
                        $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
                        $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid', array('eq' => $partnerid))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid', array('eq' => $orderid));
                        foreach($collection as $saleproduct){
                            $saleproduct->setCpprostatus(1);
                            $saleproduct->save();
                        }
                        /*sale list status update*/
                        $shipment->sendEmail(1, $comment);
                        $shipmentCreatedMessage = $this->__('The Invoice has been created.');
                        $labelCreatedMessage    = $this->__('The Invoice lable and Shipping label has been created.');
                        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($isNeedCreateLabel ? $shipmentCreatedMessage . ' ' . $labelCreatedMessage
                            : $shipmentCreatedMessage); 

                        $trackingcol1=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('seller_id ',array('in'=>$partnerid));
                        $courrier="custom";
                        foreach($trackingcol1 as $row) {
                            if($shipment->getId() != '') { 
                                $row->setShipmentId($shipment->getId());
                                $row->setInvoiceId($seller_invoice_id)->save();
                                $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                                 ->setShipment($shipment)
                                 ->setData('title',  $row->getCarrierName())
                                 ->setData('number', $row->getTrackingNumber())
                                 ->setData('carrier_code',  $courrier)
                                 ->setData('order_id', $shipment->getData('order_id'))
                                 ->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>''));
                    if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                        $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>'canceled'));
                        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                        if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                            $product_order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
                            $order->setStatus('Invoice');
                            $order->save();
                        }else{
                            $order->setStatus('Invoice');
                            $order->save();
                        }
                        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                        $historyItem = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
                            ->getUnnotifiedForInstance($order, Mage_Sales_Model_Order::HISTORY_ENTITY_NAME);
                        if ($historyItem) {
                            $historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified(1);
                            $historyItem->save();
                        }       
                    }
                    if(count($trackingsdata)==0)
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("This Order has been Invoiced Successfully");
                    else
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('This Order has been Invoiced Successfully');
                    $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));
                }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));
            }
        }
```

if i use this customer got **Shipment** mail not a **Invoice** mail How to send Invoice mail to customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$transactionSave->save();`

after that add this line to send invoice email

`$invoice->sendEmail(true, '');`

Comment: I got two mail invoice as well as shipement mail

Comment: i want only invoice mail

Comment: yes this function is performing two task because if the invoice is not create then it create invoice. this function is actually creating the shipment so customer have to get two email.

Comment: i need a shipement mail after status only

Comment: Invoice is one status Shipment is another status

Comment: this action is not setting the status it is creating them they are both apply on same time not seperately

Comment: ok but in backend if i click invoice i got only invoice mail same way i want this frontend

Comment: you have to separate function for both one for invoice and other for shipment

Comment: in front end it not possible to seperate

Comment: then you have to send both email at same time because after the invoice the shipment come you cannot send invoice email after shipment.

Comment: in backend how to change ship status

Comment: you want to change the core status of shipment?

Comment: yes if i click ship it automatically complete now i want to change shipment

Comment: if find this only related and i am not recommend this kind of solution 

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35266/adding-a-new-order-state-and-status-in-magento

Comment: How to generate shipment slip by click custom order status? is it possible. i will make a new question

Comment: yes it is possible..

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98276/magento-generate-shipping-slip

Comment: i need to see backend how it work then i will give you some solution

Comment: it's magento default function only

Comment: When we click invoice status is change processing and invoice slip will generate + i need to generate shipping slip

Comment: but on default if you create the invoice it is only creating the invoice not the shipment

Comment: you want to generate the shipping but generating the shipping automatically change the order status complete.

Comment: In front end i generate in voice it generate both invoice and shipping slip

Comment: order also remain same

Comment: on fronted you performing this custom coding. in custom you  do anything..

Comment: Ok check my updated question

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98276/magento-generate-shipping-slip#98276