# Magento generate Shipping slip

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

We are using Marketplace extension in my site, so seller also can process there own order.

i add custom order status i need to generate shipping slip after change that status

```
 public function shipmentorderAction(){
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);

                if($order->canShip())
{
    echo "check";
    exit();
$itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
    $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQty);
    $shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
    $shipmentId = $shipment->create($id);

}
                $order->setData('state', 'Shipment');
                $order->setStatus('Shipment');
                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->save(); 

                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);

                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('This Order has been Shipped Successfully')
                );
                //$this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/index');
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully'); $this->_redirectReferer();


                }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);`
after that add this code for creating the shipment

```
if($order->canShip())
{
$itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
    $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQty);
    $shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
    $shipmentId = $shipment->create($id);

}
```

Comment: No it's not generate

Comment: check it is come inside that condition `$order->canShip()`

Comment: how to check i think it is not come

Comment: use echo something in that and exit.. and check if the order is invoiced

Comment: No it's not come that

Comment: check there is invoiced generate of that order?

Comment: ya in voice generated

Comment: did you place it after the order load?

Comment: yes i think we use hasInvoices right

Comment: no we are using the right check for shipment for creating the shipment we use `canship` check

Comment: check my updated code

Comment: check with new order i just test this code it is working

Comment: I make a new order and generate invoice after that i make shipement but still its showing empty

Comment: what about after new order genrate shipment..

Comment: No it's not generating shipement

Comment: what is order status after generating the invoice?

Comment: invoice i can change processing to invoice

Comment: this code is working for me i test it  on `new order` and after `invoiced` too

Comment: order id : 100001991

Comment: check that order id

Comment: this is increment order id if your id use  this `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id);`

Comment: after loading id

Comment: echo $id; and check what is in that?

Comment: i didn't get on this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34644/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-kothari).

Comment: can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98367/magento-access-table?noredirect=1#comment132435_98367