# Magento access table

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have table called **megamenupro**.How to connect in my phtml file and access all details in my phtml file .

**Query**

```
     <?php 

     $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
     $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('megamenupro'=>'megamenupro'));
$megamenupro=$readconnection->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `megamenupro` WHERE megamenupro_id = 4 "); 

           foreach ($megamenupro as $item) {

            echo "<pre>"; print_r($item);
            echo $item['content'];

           }



?>
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [megamenupro_id] => 4
    [name] => EM0113 Best Friends Main Menu
    [type] => 0
    [content] => a:28:{i:0;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:4:"Home";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:23:"{{store direct_url=""}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon1";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:1;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:4:"Toys";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:32:"{{store direct_url="toys.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon2";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:2;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"hbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"600";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:19:"grid_22 alpha omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"1";}i:3;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"200";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:4;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:192:"PHA+PGEgc3R5bGU9InBvc2l0aW9uOnJlbGF0aXZlOyB0b3A6LTE1cHg7IiBocmVmPSIjIj48aW1nIGNsYXNzPSJmbHVpZCIgc3JjPSJ7e21lZGlhIHVybD0id3lzaXd5Zy9lbTAxMTMvYm95cy10b3lzLTIuanBnIn19IiBhbHQ9IiIgLz48L2E+PC9wPg==";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:5;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:6:"grid_4";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:6;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:1428:"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";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:7;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 alpha";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:8;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:1220:"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";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:9;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:9:"Baby Care";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:37:"{{store direct_url="baby-care.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon3";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:10;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"hbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"660";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:19:"grid_22 alpha omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"1";}i:11;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"220";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:12;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:192:"PHA+PGEgc3R5bGU9InBvc2l0aW9uOnJlbGF0aXZlOyB0b3A6LTIzcHg7IiBocmVmPSIjIj48aW1nIGNsYXNzPSJmbHVpZCIgc3JjPSJ7e21lZGlhIHVybD0id3lzaXd5Zy9lbTAxMTMvYmFieS1jYXJlLTEuanBnIn19IiBhbHQ9IiIgLz48L2E+PC9wPgoK";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:13;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"220";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:6:"grid_4";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:14;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:1276:"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";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:15;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 alpha";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:16;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:192:"PHA+PGEgc3R5bGU9InBvc2l0aW9uOnJlbGF0aXZlOyB0b3A6LTE1cHg7IiBocmVmPSIjIj48aW1nIGNsYXNzPSJmbHVpZCIgc3JjPSJ7e21lZGlhIHVybD0id3lzaXd5Zy9lbTAxMTMvYmFieS1jYXJlMi5qcGcifX0iIGFsdD0iIiIgLz48L2E+PC9wPgo=";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:17;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:15:"School Supplies";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:34:"{{store direct_url="school.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon4";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:18;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"hbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"660";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:19:"grid_22 alpha omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"1";}i:19;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"220";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:20;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:156:"PHA+PGEgaHJlZj0iIyI+PGltZyBjbGFzcz0iZmx1aWQiIHNyYz0ie3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvZW0wMTEzL3NjaG9vbC1zdXBwbGllcy1pbWFnZTEuanBnIn19IiBhbHQ9IiIgLz48L2E+PC9wPgo=";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:21;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"220";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:6:"grid_4";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:22;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:900:"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";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:23;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 alpha";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:24;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:360:"PGJyIC8+PGJyIC8+Cjx1bD4KPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9Ii9zY2hvb2wvY29tcHV0ZXItYWNjZXNzb3JpZXMuaHRtbCI+Q29tcHV0ZXIgQWNjZXNzb3JpZXM8L2E+PC9saT4KPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9Ii9zY2hvb2wvc3RhdGlvbmVyeS5odG1sIj5TdGF0aW9uZXJ5PC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaT48YSBocmVmPSIvc2Nob29sL3dhdGVyLWJvdHRsZXMuaHRtbCI+V2F0ZXIgQm90dGxlczwvYT48L2xpPgo8bGk+PGEgaHJlZj0iL3NjaG9vbC9tdWdzLmh0bWwiPk11Z3M8L2E+PC9saT4KPC91bD4=";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:25;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:9:"Furniture";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:38:"{{store direct_url="furnitures.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon2";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:26;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:13:"Mobile Covers";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:34:"{{store direct_url="mobile.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon5";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:27;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:7:"contact";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:38:"{{store direct_url='contact-us.html'}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon2";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}}
    [css_class] => 
    [status] => 1
    [created_time] => 2016-01-21 15:57:49
    [update_time] => 2016-01-21 15:57:49
)
a:28:{i:0;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:4:"Home";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:23:"{{store direct_url=""}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon1";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:1;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:4:"Toys";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:32:"{{store direct_url="toys.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon2";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:2;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"hbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"600";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:19:"grid_22 alpha omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"1";}i:3;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"200";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:4;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:192:"PHA+PGEgc3R5bGU9InBvc2l0aW9uOnJlbGF0aXZlOyB0b3A6LTE1cHg7IiBocmVmPSIjIj48aW1nIGNsYXNzPSJmbHVpZCIgc3JjPSJ7e21lZGlhIHVybD0id3lzaXd5Zy9lbTAxMTMvYm95cy10b3lzLTIuanBnIn19IiBhbHQ9IiIgLz48L2E+PC9wPg==";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:5;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:6:"grid_4";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:6;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:1428:"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";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:7;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 alpha";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:8;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:1220:"PGJyIC8+PGJyIC8+Cjx1bD4KPGxpIGNsYXNzPSJwYXJlbnQiPjxhIGhyZWY9Ii90b3lzL2VsZWN0cm9uaWMtdG95cy5odG1sIj4gRWxlY3Ryb25pYyBUb3lzIDwvYT4KPHVsPgo8bGk+PGEgaHJlZj0iL3RveXMvZWxlY3Ryb25pYy10b3lzL3ZpZGVvLWdhbWVzLmh0bWwiPiBWaWRlbyBHYW1lcyA8L2E+PC9saT4KPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9Ii90b3lzL2VsZWN0cm9uaWMtdG95cy9jYXItdG95cy1vbmxpbmUuaHRtbCI+IENhcnMgPC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaT48YSBocmVmPSIvdG95cy9lbGVjdHJvbmljLXRveXMvaGVsZWNvcHRlci10b3lzLmh0bWwiPiBIZWxpY29wdGVyPC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaT48YSBocmVmPSIvdG95cy9lbGVjdHJvbmljLXRveXMvcm9ib3RpY3MtdG95cy5odG1sIj4gUm9ib3RzPC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaT48YSBocmVmPSIvdG95cy9lbGVjdHJvbmljLXRveXMvdG95LWJpa2VzLW9ubGluZS5odG1sIj4gQmlrZXM8L2E+PC9saT4KPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9Ii90b3lzL2VsZWN0cm9uaWMtdG95cy90YW5rcy10cnVja3MtdG95cy5odG1sIj4gVGFua3MgJmFtcDsgVHJ1Y2tzPC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaT48YSBocmVmPSIvdG95cy9lbGVjdHJvbmljLXRveXMvdHJhaW4tc2V0LXRveXMtZm9yLWtpZHMuaHRtbCI+IFRyYWluIFNldDwvYT48L2xpPgo8L3VsPgo8L2xpPgo8bGk+PGEgaHJlZj0iL3RveXMvdG95cy1mb3ItYmFiaWVzLmh0bWwiPiBUb3lzIGZvciBCYWJpZXMgPC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaT48YSBocmVmPSIvdG95cy9yaWRlLW9uLXRveXMtZm9yLWtpZHMuaHRtbCI+UmlkZSBPbiB0b3lzPC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaT48YSBocmVmPSIvdG95cy9kaWVjYXN0Lmh0bWwiPkRpZWNhc3QgVG95czwvYT48L2xpPgo8bGk+PGEgaHJlZj0iL3RveXMvYWN0aXZpdHkuaHRtbCI+QWN0aXZpdHkgVG95czwvYT48L2xpPgo8L3VsPgoK";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:9;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:9:"Baby Care";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:37:"{{store direct_url="baby-care.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon3";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:10;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"hbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"660";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:19:"grid_22 alpha omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"1";}i:11;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"220";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:12;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:192:"PHA+PGEgc3R5bGU9InBvc2l0aW9uOnJlbGF0aXZlOyB0b3A6LTIzcHg7IiBocmVmPSIjIj48aW1nIGNsYXNzPSJmbHVpZCIgc3JjPSJ7e21lZGlhIHVybD0id3lzaXd5Zy9lbTAxMTMvYmFieS1jYXJlLTEuanBnIn19IiBhbHQ9IiIgLz48L2E+PC9wPgoK";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:13;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"220";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:6:"grid_4";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:14;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:1276:"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";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:15;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 alpha";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:16;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:192:"PHA+PGEgc3R5bGU9InBvc2l0aW9uOnJlbGF0aXZlOyB0b3A6LTE1cHg7IiBocmVmPSIjIj48aW1nIGNsYXNzPSJmbHVpZCIgc3JjPSJ7e21lZGlhIHVybD0id3lzaXd5Zy9lbTAxMTMvYmFieS1jYXJlMi5qcGcifX0iIGFsdD0iIiIgLz48L2E+PC9wPgo=";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:17;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:15:"School Supplies";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:34:"{{store direct_url="school.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon4";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:18;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"hbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"660";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:19:"grid_22 alpha omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"1";}i:19;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"220";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 omega";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:20;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:156:"PHA+PGEgaHJlZj0iIyI+PGltZyBjbGFzcz0iZmx1aWQiIHNyYz0ie3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvZW0wMTEzL3NjaG9vbC1zdXBwbGllcy1pbWFnZTEuanBnIn19IiBhbHQ9IiIgLz48L2E+PC9wPgo=";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:21;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:3:"220";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:6:"grid_4";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:22;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:900:"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";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:23;a:7:{s:4:"type";s:4:"vbox";s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:7:"spacing";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:12:"grid_4 alpha";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"2";}i:24;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:4:"text";s:4:"text";s:360:"PGJyIC8+PGJyIC8+Cjx1bD4KPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9Ii9zY2hvb2wvY29tcHV0ZXItYWNjZXNzb3JpZXMuaHRtbCI+Q29tcHV0ZXIgQWNjZXNzb3JpZXM8L2E+PC9saT4KPGxpPjxhIGhyZWY9Ii9zY2hvb2wvc3RhdGlvbmVyeS5odG1sIj5TdGF0aW9uZXJ5PC9hPjwvbGk+CjxsaT48YSBocmVmPSIvc2Nob29sL3dhdGVyLWJvdHRsZXMuaHRtbCI+V2F0ZXIgQm90dGxlczwvYT48L2xpPgo8bGk+PGEgaHJlZj0iL3NjaG9vbC9tdWdzLmh0bWwiPk11Z3M8L2E+PC9saT4KPC91bD4=";s:9:"css_class";s:0:"";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"3";}i:25;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:9:"Furniture";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:38:"{{store direct_url="furnitures.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon2";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:26;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:13:"Mobile Covers";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:34:"{{store direct_url="mobile.html"}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon5";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}i:27;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:4:"link";s:5:"label";s:7:"contact";s:8:"sublabel";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:38:"{{store direct_url='contact-us.html'}}";s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:9:"css_class";s:7:"m_icon2";s:13:"container_css";s:0:"";s:5:"depth";s:1:"0";}}
```

My problem is it showing encrypted value how to decrypt.

Comment: There are a lot of guides on how to build a Magento module and connecting to a custom table. Your question as it is now would require writing an entire guide on writing Magento Modules and thats not what this site is for.

Comment: Please see my answer everything is explained, how to get access to the table, how to fetch data.

Comment: actually i want use in my .phtml file already module is there

Comment: See my edited answer to know how to use collection in phtml file

Comment: Please provide a full explained answer, with all your edits and all your existing files

Comment: Acutally i want to get details of megamenupro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will get data with below query

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
     $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('megamenupro'=>'megamenupro'));
$megamenupro=$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord); 

           foreach ($megamenupro as $item) {

            echo "<pre>"; print_r($item);
            echo $item['column_name'];

           }
```

Comment: ya it's working but contents are encrypted how to encrypted

Comment: you have to check the encryption then you can do decryption that.

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: sorry you have to check encryption by yourself no idea about that.

Comment: can you please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98367/magento-access-table/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Model and Resource for that.
Here you can find how to do that directly in the Magento documentation : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html
You can cross informations with this tutorial : http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model/

---

If you want to access into a phtml file, simply use a foreach on the collection variable.

```
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    // use $item object as a traduction of a single table line 
    // If you want to debug the object data
    Zend_Debug::dump($item->debug());
}
```

Comment: Check my updated question what is the problem